# Column vector of simultaneous equaations' solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Struggling with some basics of Linear Algebra. Please help.

Let's restrict the discussion to 2D space & consider the following simultaneous equations:
$2x + 3y = 8,
x + 2y = 5$

I understand these are two straight lines, with a solution at $x = 1 , y = 2$
So far so good, now things start to get fuzzy when we express this in a Matrix form.

We say that when the matrix of coefficients $(2, 3, 1, 2) $transforms the vector of unknowns $(x, y)$, we get the column vector$ (8, 5)$.

But I'm not able to understand why is $(8, 5)$ a vector?

To me, both 8 & 5 represent two straight lines in the 2D space according to the simultaneous equations above, whereas a vector is essentially a point in the 2D space with specific x & y coordinates, eg solution to the equations $(1, 2)$represents a vector. But why is $(8, 5)$ considered a vector when these are two different straight lines with only a single point of intersection?

Please help me understand.

Comment: You know what is matrix and don't understand what is vector?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the formula $$ \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 8 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix},$$ which  gives the specific system of equations you described. However, we transformed the system of equations into an equation involving vectors.

You might consider matrix $A$ as a representation of a linear transformation that maps any vector with coordinates $(x,y)$ to another vector in the $2-$D plane. Namely,  we have the linear transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (2x+3y,x+2y),$ or equivalently $T(x,y) = (2x+3y, x+2y)$.

In our example, we want to find the initial vector with coordinates $(x,y)$ such that $T(x,y) = (8,5)$.

Comment: thanks @thanasissdr, the LHS side is clear to me now. Matrix A transforms any vector with coordinates (x,y) to (2x+3y, x+2y). That much is clear now. But (8, 5) represent two different lines with their set of (x,y) values according to their linear equations. i.e., (8,5) is not a coordinate. 8 doesn't represent x alone & 5 doesn't represent y alone. So why is (8,5) considered a vector?

Comment: The intersection of the $2$ above linear equations is a point and not a vector. Because we are in $\mathbb R^2$, we need  $2$ co - ordinates to describe where the point of intersection is located according to a reference point. Usually, that point is the axes origin. Points have no direction. Vectors do have magnitude and direction.

Comment: To every point $A$ in $\mathbb R^2$ we can assign a vector with the same co-ordinates. To do so, we just have to connect the point $A$ with the axes origin. Now, having said that, you can see that we have a  vector with co - ordinates $(x,y)$  and through the linear transformation we want to map this vector to the vector with co - ordinates $(8,5).$